# Paging control for windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

Various paging controls are available for web apps but anyone could tell me is there any good paging control for win apps. IF so then please give me the url.

Comment: Whats wrong with the gridview control?

Comment: WPF and WinForms are two different framework, and may provide different solutions. So tell us what do you want? Be specific!

Comment: Because the question is ambiguous in that area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataGrid with paging](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridPaging.aspx)