# .net's ListBox data(large) takes too much time to show up

Tags: .net, vb.net, listbox

Im a .net newbie, I ran into a problem where the listbox is taking awfully long time to show up.

This is not the same in java(It took very very less time - one second max).

So, is there any remedy to this??, any other form control??, or some other way??

```
imports System.Threading
imports System.Windows.Forms

Class form1
         Inherits Form

    Public d As Object() = New Object(400000) {}

    Private lb As ListBox
    Public Sub New()
        lb = New ListBox()
        Controls.Add(lb)
    End Sub

    Public Sub update_list()
        For i As Integer = 0 To 400000
            d(i) = i
        Next
        lb.DataSource = d
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub main()
        Dim fobj As New form1()
        Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf fobj.ShowDialog)
        t.Start()
        Dim t2 As New Thread(AddressOf fobj.update_list)
            t2.Start()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I am not in to vb.net but noticed one thing that the counter in update_list from 0 to 400000 might be the issue

Comment: u mean the delay might be in the for loop???...If yes, I dont think so, its definetely in the 'lb.DataSource = d'

Comment: yes might be when calling 
d(i) = i
next i

Comment: no, cant be so....check it by putting console.writelines before and after 'lb.DataSource = d'.  u'll see that this the one causing the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a control that supports paging, because humans cannot handle this amount of data at one time (regardless of whether the control does).

[Here](http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_paging.htm) is one way of using DataGrid that way.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848440/paging-control-for-windows-application).

Comment: You are a saviour!!. The DataGridView with a BindingSource makes no delay. For further info - not only tables, but also a wrapped object array with our item as its first property can also be bounded